# SurveyMonkey API - get all contacts

Tags: surveymonkey

I am trying to get all contacts from SurveyMonkey's API, so I can process who is in the system and who is not.

SurveyMonkey has a `/contacts` endpoint ([see here](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#contacts)).  We are finding that this only shows active contacts by default. To get bounced or opted out contacts I'd need to make 3 total requests.

Is there a way to search all 3 status types (`active`, `bounced`, `optout`) with one `GET` request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible at this time. You need to make one request for each status. We'll add it to our list of requested enhancements and reply to this question if and when it's implemented.